# Sync channel permissions with category permissions discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

I'm making a bot that can change the permissions of all the channels in the server the command was run in. But if I wanted the bot to change the permissions back, I want it to sync the permissions with the categories permissions. How can I do this with discord.py?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a `sync_permissions` option that you can pass to [`edit`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.TextChannel.edit).

```
await channel.edit(sync_permissions=True)
```